# Unable to connect to Azure Analysis Services via Azure Function App - Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext'

Tags: c#, azure, ssas, azure-functions, azure-analysis-services

Following [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/automating-azure-analysis-services-processing-with-azure-functions/) guide, I have created an Azure Function App that compiles and runs:

```
#r "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DLL"
#r "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.DLL"
#r "System.Configuration"

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;

// req is a value passed from function.json which is currently ignored
public static void Run(String req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function started at: {DateTime.Now}");

    try
            {
                Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server asSrv = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server();

                // Pulls the connection string from the Connection Strings collection within the Application Settings
                //var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AASDev"].ConnectionString;

                // Pulls the connection string from an Environment Variable held within the Application Settings collection
                //var connStr = GetEnvironmentVariable("Conn");

                // Simply hard coding the connection string (Anonymised)
                var connStr = @"Data Source=asazure://<roll out>.asazure.windows.net/<My AAS Instance>;Initial Catalog=<My AAS Database>;User ID=<My User>;Password=<My Pass>";

                asSrv.Connect(connStr);
                Database db = asSrv.Databases["<My AAS Database>"];
                Model m = db.Model;
                m.Tables["<My AAS Table>"].RequestRefresh(RefreshType.Full);     // Mark only one table for refresh
                db.Model.SaveChanges();     //commit  which will execute the refresh
                asSrv.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function exception: {e.ToString()}");
            }
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function finished at: {DateTime.Now}"); 
}
```

When running the function however, an exception is thrown when it tries to connect to the server object held within the `asSrv` variable:

```
2018-11-12T13:45:40.273 [Information] C# Timer trigger function exception: 
System.TypeLoadException:
  Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<removed>'.  
    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.IdentityResolver.Dispose()  
    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)  
    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Connect(String connectionString, String sessionId, ObjectExpansion expansionType)  
    at Submission#0.Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
```

The connection string has the `User ID` and `Password` set as per the example and no matter how I try formatting or retrieving this connection string it either throws the above error or complains that there isn't a user or password where omitted.

What am I missing here?

---

Edit for Runtime ~1:

Currently getting many instances of the following error message:

```
2018-11-13T10:02:42.817 [Warning] Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio, PublicKeyToken=xxx'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
2018-11-13T10:02:42.817 [Warning] Exception during runtime resolution of assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio, PublicKeyToken=xxx': 'System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

   at System.AppDomain.nApplyPolicy(AssemblyName an)

   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionAssemblyLoader.ResolveAssemblyCore(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\FunctionAssemblyLoader.cs:line 88'
2018-11-13T10:02:42.817 [Warning] Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio, PublicKeyToken=xxx'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
2018-11-13T10:02:43.676 [Warning] Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.resources, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=xxx'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
2018-11-13T10:02:43.676 [Warning] Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.resources, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=xxx'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
```

Comment: See my newly update, you could just ignore those warnings if connection succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial is for Function on runtime ~1 which targets at .Net Framework. While right now Function app is on .Net Core runtime ~2 by default.

Go to Portal, Platform features> Application settings, under Application settings section, set `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to ~1. Note that all functions created before will be influenced.

**Update**

Without .Net Core SDK support, we probably can't make it work in Funtion 2.x runtime. And those warnings of missing assemblies in ~1 runtime should be harmless.

If you meet error `On-Premise Gateway is required to access the data source. Please install a unified gateway for the server`, please follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway) to install.

Comment: What changes would be required to replicate this functionality on .Net Core runtime ~2?

Comment: @iamdave Probably just give up using those assemblies and find other method to authenticate, like rest api. Internally those assemblies tried to find references which are not available in .net core env, it's more than an Azure function problem.

Comment: *find other method to authenticate* - Such as?  How else is one supposed to connect to an Azure Tabular Model without using the Tabular DLLs referenced in the tutorial?

Comment: Also, changing to runtime ~1 causes a bunch of missing reference errors, so I am assuming that isn't the actual problem here

Comment: @iamdave If you want to move on with ~1, could you provide those missing error so I can offer help? On my side, I was stopped by the `asSrv.Connect(connStr)` with some authentication problem as I have multiple authentication factor set and can't log in directly so I think runtime ~1 could work for you. If you want to work with ~2 runtime, you could try [other packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-data-providers#amo-and-adomd-nuget-packages) in that tutorial.

Comment: @iamdave Unfortunately those packages seem all not compatible with .net core, see same `System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext` error on my side and find one [related issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/17573) .

Comment: @iamdave  Do you need further help with ~1 runtime or let's call it a day?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183546/discussion-between-jerry-liu-and-iamdave).