# How to build a c# code to backup a tabular database with REST API?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, backup, ssas-tabular

I'm looking for a solution or at least some advice on how to build a function app in c# allowing to backup a tabular database hosted on an SSAS Azure Instance using the REST API. Idea is to backup it on an azure storage.

I've seen several code for SQL but I don't find any relevant documentation or sample.
Thanks for your help,
Miguel

At this moment I've start with this but I've got errors

```
 string ConnectionString = "Provider = MSOLAP; Data Source = asazure://northeurope.asazure.wxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


            // 
            // The using syntax ensures the correct use of the 
            // Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server object. 
            // 
            using (Server server = new Server())
            {

                server.Connect(ConnectionString); }
```

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: Error : Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: Is the [answer contained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265161/unable-to-connect-to-azure-analysis-services-via-azure-function-app-could-not) of any help to you?

Comment: yes and no :(  .We would like to build that in c# and I would like to avoir to mix c# with powershell (which is use for the runbooks <-- we are not allowed to use the runbooks).